# How to output lowest and highest numbers from list into tuple?

Tags: python

Sorry if I'm asking a stupid question.
So I'm studying Python and my homework is to find the lowest and highest number from list and then insert it into a tuple.

Right now this is the code I have (highlighted is my code):

```
import random

**def minimum_maximum(integer_list):

   l.sort()
   l = [l[0], l[-1]]
   minimum_maximum = tuple(l)**




l = []
for i in range(random.randint(15,25)):
  l.append(random.randint(-150,150))
       
print ("List:", l)
print ("Minimum and maximum:",minimum_maximum(l))
```

I can edit only the highlighted code. Right now the problem is "local variable 'l' referenced before assignment" which I tried to google, but I simply don't understand how to fix this. How can I make this work?

Comment: Sorry it didn't highlight the code! But I meant the code part with "**".

Comment: Your function has parameter `integer_list` but then you are trying to access it using variable name `l`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function, the input parameter is `integer_list` but you use `l` that is undefined:

```
def minimum_maximum(integer_list):
   l.sort()
   l = [l[0], l[-1]]
   minimum_maximum = tuple(l)
```

Corrected version:

```
def minimum_maximum(integer_list):
   l = sorted(integer_list)  # using `sorted` to create a copy
   return (l[0], l[-1])      # returning the tuple directly
```

*NB. note that **sorting the full list** is not the most efficient method (although probably the shortest code). Ideally you should loop over the elements **once** and update the minimum and maximum as you go*

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems:

1. Your function receives the parameter `integer_list` but instead of using it, you're using `l`.
2. You're trying to assign the result to a variable that is named the same way the function is (`minimum_maximum`). Instead just return the result.
3. Just for clarity, you can immediately `return (integer_list[0], integer_list[-1])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `min()` and `max()` functions, which return the lowest and highest values of your list respectively:

```
def maximum_minimum(integer_list):
    return (min(integer_list), max(integer_list))
```